# Correct way to write the polar form of a complex number

Tags: complex-numbers, polar-coordinates

What is the most correct way to write the polar form of a complex number?

For example, given the complex number: $\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2} + \dfrac{1}{2}i$ I would write the polar form as follows:

\begin{align}
  \dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2} + \frac 12 i &= \cos\left(\frac{\pi}{6}\right)+i\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{6}\right) \\
 &= e^{i{\pi}/{6}}
\end{align}

My question is what about every other integer multiple of $2\pi$? Should I write this as: $e^{i\pi/{6} + 2\pi k}$ for $k\in\mathbb{N}$

Thanks for the help!

Comment: As long as there are no specific conditions required, I think your way is fine.

Comment: Note you want to add $2\pi i k$, not $2\pi k$.

Comment: For "$k\in\mathbb N$" read "$k\in\mathbb Z$".